# FormUrlEncodedContent Serializeable Class

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes, urlencode, key-value

I would like to create a class such as:

```
public class Transaction
{
    [SerializeAs("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

That I could then convert to an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` for consumption by `FormUrlEncodedContent` (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client)

I have also created my custom attribute as such:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class SerializeAs : System.Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SerializeAs(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

and can convert my class to an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`with:

```
 public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ToDictionary(object myObj)
    {
        return myObj.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(pi => new {Name = pi.Name, Value = pi.GetValue(myObj, null).ToString()})
            .Union(
                myObj.GetType()
                    .GetFields()
                    .Select(fi => new {Name = fi.Name, Value = fi.GetValue(myObj).ToString()})
            )
            .ToDictionary(ks => ks.Name, vs => vs.Value);
    }
```

However I am unsure how to implement the attribute functionality intended for `[SerializeAs]` inside my `ToDictionary` method, any help would be greatly appreciated.